# What is the difference between Model B+ v1.2 and Model 2B v1.1

Tags: pi-2, pi-models, pi-b+

I have read a few threads and a wiki page, but I am still getting confused.

Until now I have used RPi Model B+ v1.2 and since it has 40 GPIOs, 4x USB and stuff, I supposed it is the RPi 2. Today I have received RPi 2 Model B v1.1 for my new project. It also has 40 GPIOs, 4x USB, but has a different CPU (or whatever that is, it says Broadcom instead of Samsung) AND it has a smaller Raspberry drawn on it. They both claim to be copyrighted in 2014.

So... which is newer (supposedly better)? Main differences?

Answer (score 18):

The B+ had a single core Broadcom BCM2835 Arm 6, with 512MB of RAM. 
the Raspberry Pi 2 (is newer) has a quad core BCM2836 Arm 7, with 1GB of RAM. As a result of the quad core CPU the Raspberry Pi 2 has a higher current draw.

Adafruit put together a nice [comparison](https://learn.adafruit.com/introducing-the-raspberry-pi-2-model-b?view=all) of the two, that includes a section detailing how to tell them apart.

Comment: Also note that the memory was physically moved between the B+ and the 2B. On the B+ the memory is stacked on top of the processor. On the 2B it's on the back of the PCB.

Answer (score 6):

The Pi2 has four cores, see https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-2-model-b/

The B+ (like all the other Pis apart from the Pi2) has a single core, see https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-1-model-b/

Answer (score 6):

If *more* is *better* the Pi2 clearly wins. Double size of RAM (1 GB vs. 512 MB) could make the difference for demanding applications.

The Pi2's quad-core CPU @ 900 MHz vs. single-core CPU @ 700 MHz, obviously provides more computational power. The [blog @ RPi.org](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/raspberry-pi-2-on-sale/) claims an performance increase up to 6x (expect that value highly dependent on the application).

All that comes at a certain price and that would be an increased power consumption (see [here](http://www.pidramble.com/wiki/benchmarks/power-consumption) and [here](http://raspi.tv/2015/raspberry-pi2-power-and-performance-measurement) for some figures).